# How to add new entries to an entity's collection in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

Let's say there is a class as follows:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
class OauthUser(
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var oauthAttributes: List<OauthAttribute>,

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    var email: String,
    var firstName: String,
    var lastName: String
) : OAuth2User {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    var id: Long? = null

}
```

I am trying to add new entries of `oauthAttributes` when a user logs in again after initially logging in, so that if there is an updated attribute, a new attribute is created to keep a history of profle changes.

I am not able to `userRepository.findByEmail(email).oauthAttributes.add(newEntry)` because oauthAttributes is defined as a List, which doesn't have the add method. When I try to cast it to ArrayList I get the following error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag cannot be cast to class java.util.ArrayList`.

How can I go about adding an entry into that lits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running into this issue again I've realised that there is something I was missing:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
var oauthAttributes: List<OauthAttribute>,
```

In Kotlin, **List** is of a non-mutable type and hence does not contain the method add, nor can it be cast to a mutable collection.
In order to achieve what the original question was asking, the field definition needs to be changed to **MutableList**, like so:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
var oauthAttributes: MutableList<OauthAttribute>,
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing some reading and experimenting I found that the following works:

1. Create a reference to the user in the `OauthAttribute` class, like so:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @NotNull
    lateinit var user: OauthUser
```

2. Adjust the `oauthAttributes` collection definition in the `OauthUser` class, from

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var oauthAttributes: List<OauthAttribute>,
```

to

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    var oauthAttributes: List<OauthAttribute>?
```

This will create a `user_id` foreign key reference in the oauth_attribute table instead of a separate join table. Now it is possible to simply create new instances of the `OauthAttribute` class and assign them to the user by simply specifying assigning the `user` class property to the corresponding user.

I welcome any comments in case that solution isn't optimal. Also, I believe the question still stands for many to many relationships.